# In drupal, do I need to update after "site install"ing using drush?

Tags: drupal, installation, drush

When I use drush to site install (drush si profileName), do I need to run an update so all the modules will run what they need as part as their update methods, or does a fresh "site install" doesn't require an update ?

If it matters, I'm talking about drupal 7. RC1 to be exact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`drush site-install` does the same thing as a GUI site install: that is, it only installs local install profiles and does not update. The reason is presumably installation profiles are designed and tested around specific versions of modules.

You can update after the site install by running `drush update`.

In terms of whether or not you should run update.php (i.e. `drush updatedb`) after a site install to get the latest changes from [`hook_update_N()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_update_N) and [`hook_install()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--install.php/function/hook_install), you don't need to worry about it. `hook_install()` should always contain the latest version of the module's schema, and `hook_install()` is always invoked the first time a module is enabled.

Comment: My question is whether I'm supposed to update after a fresh install using "drush site-install" ?
Are the creators of the different modules make sure the hook_install be current, or do they keep it the same as it was when they first created it, and expect me to run the update so the updateN hooks will run ?

Comment: @Doron I've updated my answer: you don't have to worry about it. `hook_install()` will be called during site install, and `hook_install()` should always contain the latest schema definition (that is, if it doesn't, the module is broken).